# Reconnect the front panel connectors of a eMachines computer

Tags: motherboard, front-panel, jumper

I replaced my IDE hard drive in my eMachine  computer and accidentally disconnected the jumpers Power Led, HDD Led and Power SW and would like to connect 
them back correctly.

How can I fix it?

System: Windows 7, hard drive IDE Maxtor

Comment: Check your motherboard manual is what I would suggest first.

Comment: I always take a picture of stuff like that before disconnecting, unless there is a manual from emachines you are out of luck.

Comment: There are multiple eMachines PC models with multiple motherboards. Without the model number, we can't find the right set of instructions to show you how to reconnect those wires. Please provide the model number printed on the same sticker which has the serial number, then click [edit] and add that essential information to the question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead use [edit].

Answer (score 1):

1) Using the model number of the PC, look up its hardware and maintenance manual at the [manufacturer's website](http://www.emachines.com/ec/en/US/content/drivers.html). Find the pins on the motherboard to connect the wiring to.

2) Wiring for LEDs is often color coded, because LEDs need to be connected with the correct polarity to work. They won't break if reverse the wiring, so if the wires are not color coded, you can try the wires in one position, and if that does not work, reverse them to try reverse polarity.

3) The Power Switch wires do not care about polarity; the power on circuit on the motherboard will accept its wires regardless of polarity.